# How to write nested loops in JSX to reduce repetitive code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The following code outputs two separate form sections. Everything works fine but I have two for() loops that are similar and two map() functions that are also similar.  I want to learn how to write a nested script with the for() loop and map() function so that I can add more properties to my state.program object and my form will update automatically without me having to add another for() or map().

Basically I'm trying to loop through the object, create arrays to map to my component props. I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

I hope the description of my problem makes sense.  Here are the React Components...

```
class CreateProgram extends Component {
  state = {
    program: {
      description: {
        title: {
          label: 'Program title',
          value: ''
        },
        category: {
          label: 'Program category',
          value: ''
        }
      },
      location: {
        location_title: {
          label: 'location title',
          value: ''
        },
        location_coor: {
          label: 'location coordinates',
          value: null
        }
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <Program items={this.state.program} />;
  }
}
export default CreateProgram;

class Program extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const descriptionArray = [];
    const locationArray = [];

    for (let key in items.description) {
      descriptionArray.push({
        id: key,
        value: items.description[key]
      });
    }
    for (let key in items.location) {
      locationArray.push({
        id: key,
        value: items.location[key]
      });
    }

    return (
      <>
        <div className="form-section">
          {descriptionArray.map(element => (
            <Input
              label={element.value.label}
              value={element.value.value}
              changed={event =>
                changed(event, element.id, 'program', 'description')
              }
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="form-section">
          {locationArray.map(element => (
            <Input
              label={element.value.label}
              value={element.value.value}
              changed={event =>
                changed(event, element.id, 'program', 'location')
              }
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Program;
```

Comment: You could use `Object.keys()` to iterate over the keys of your object. You could do that with both levels: program and it's sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the parent state:

```
state = {
    description: {
        title: {
            label: "Program title",
            value: ""
        },
        category: {
            label: "Program category",
            value: ""
        }
    },
    location: {
        location_title: {
            label: "location title",
            value: ""
        },
        location_coor: {
            label: "location coordinates",
            value: null
        }
    }
};
```

Then pass these separately to the child component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Program
            description={this.state.description}
            location={this.state.location}
        />
    );
};
```

And in the child component use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returned array to map each element:

```
Object.entries(this.props.description).map(([key, value]) => (
    <Input
        key={key}
        label={value.label}
        value={value.value}
        changed={event => changed(event, key, "program", "description")}
    />
));
```

```
Object.entries(this.props.location).map(([key, value]) => (
    <Input
        key={key}
        label={value.label}
        value={value.value}
        changed={event => changed(event, key, "program", "location")}
    />
));
```

Comment: Thanks Alvaro,  This would work.  However, the main objective is to be able to just update the state with new properties and not have to 'manually create' write the  Object.entries .... map()  script each time. 

That is why I nested the program object in state. So that if I added a new item to the state.program it would automatically render a new input.

Comment: @Tammy You're welcome. So what you would want is to be able to pass any kind of key inside `program` and the child component should render these without knowing which are? In that case I guess a loop inside a loop (1st loop program properties, 2nd loop each of those values properties) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I think you go it.  But let me try and make it clearer.

I would want update state.program with and property.  e.g

`program: {
description: {...},
location: {...},
accommodation: {... new data}
}`

And the child component should render another <input>

So as you said: (1st loop program properties, 2nd loop each of those values properties)

But don't know how to write the nested loop.